# Looking for Flutter Library for Image Slideshow with Audio Playing (Behaves just like a Video)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm looking for a flutter library that acts just like a video player. But instead of a video file, I want to pass an array of images which switch at specific time intervals. While this "slideshow" is playing, an audio clip will play - the slideshow should essentially behave like a video.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a package that does both. But how about combining [`carousel_slider`](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) with either [`audioplayers`](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) or [`just_audio`](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio).